# Docker Data Container Encryption

Tags: encryption, docker, public-key-encryption

I am not sure if this is feasible with current Docker/Linux, so I have this question. I am looking for advices, tools and How-To's in order to achieve this.

I want to add optional encryption to my existing Docker containers. My preferred choice is exposing volumes through a data container. The data container manages encryption and is provided with the encryption credentials:

- Data container has volume /data
- Data container has encryption credentials (Password or Key).
- Data written to /data is written on a host directory encrypted using the data containers credentials.
- Data read from /data can only be done through the data container.

The application container:

- Application mounts data container with the Docker parameter -v
- Application container Writes and Reads without any regards to encryption and decryption to and from data container.